# How can I convert JSON Array to array in PHP?

Tags: php

```
{
  "receiver_uid":[
          "58a43a3e3fbbf3.61108490",
          "58a43be07a3bc3.90311110",
          "58da53ab5ce8d6.84754819"
  ]
}
```

This is the value I would like to convert to array. I know it's quite a simple question, but please can anyone help me?

Comment: Use `json_decode` method

Comment: @SahilGulati I know, but I was really urgent to get the answer.

Comment: Try to use post of @NishantNair

Comment: @MarshallS.Lee Please review http://stackoverflow.com/a/43384104/2667307

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `json_decode`

```
json_decode($your_jsonString,true)
```

Answer (score 4):

You should use [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

Try this:

```
$data = json_decode($your_json_string, TRUE);
```

The **second** parameter will make decoded json string into an associative arrays.

**Example :-**

```
$data = '{"receiver_uid":["58a43a3e3fbbf3.61108490","58a43be07a3bc3.90311110","58da53ab5ce8d6.84754819"]}';
$array = json_decode($data, true);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);
```

> Output would be like

```
Array
(
    [receiver_uid] => Array
        (
            [0] => 58a43a3e3fbbf3.61108490
            [1] => 58a43be07a3bc3.90311110
            [2] => 58da53ab5ce8d6.84754819
        )

)
```